# Git is not updating

Tags: debian, upgrade, git

I am new to linux, and I have just installed `git` using,

`sudo apt-get install git-all`

When I attempted to restore a file after making modifications, I get the following error:

`git: 'restore' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.`

I did some research, and it turns out that `git restore` was not implemented until git version 2.23.0. I then ran,

`git --version`

And saw that I had 2.20.1 installed. To update git, I ran,

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get --only-upgrade install git-all`

It told me that `git-all is already the newest version (1:2.20.1-2+deb10u3)`, but this is not the latest version of git. The latest version of git is 2.34.1. What is happening here and how can I update git?

Comment: Debian Buster only goes up to 2.20 for git. Either install from source, or upgrade to bullseye. There are probably more options, but I am not familiar enough with Debian to advise on those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download the latest version here:
https://git-scm.com/download/linux

URL: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/git-2.34.1.tar.gz

then make it.